# Importing a CSV File into Java

Tags: java, csv

In the program I am writing, I want to be able to import CSV files. At the moment, it takes a basic text file in.

```
File mainemails = new File ("mainemails.txt");
```

I know that for CSV imports using File is probably not the most time-efficient thing to use. What would be the most efficient way to import a CSV file? Would I have to download any new libraries to use an efficient method?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/101100/csv-api-for-java

Comment: You should use [open CSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) and if you wish to work with Microsoft Office Tools (like doc, docx, xls, xlsx etc), you can use [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/download.html) Java API.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [opencsv](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) for importing csv data and then constructing objects from it.

I prefer using libraries so that I can save development time. Also they tend to solve specific problems better.

Comment: Where would I save the library to?

Comment: @ Nick Welki : I did not understand the question. You can save the library anywhere in your machine. Please go through SO questions relevant to your IDE. Adding a jar to a project is well discussed.

Answer (score 5):

Try [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101100/csv-api-for-java) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7712524/java-import-csv-to-arraylist).