# Importing a CSV file into an ArrayList and converting values in Java

Tags: java, csv, arraylist

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
   String fileloc = "src\\assignment12\\Areas.csv";
   List<data> list = new ArrayList<data>();
    try {
       BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileloc));
       String line = null;
       String read = br.readLine();
       while (read != null){

        String temp[] = read.split(",");  

        list.add(new data(temp[0], temp[1], temp[2], temp[3], temp[4]));

     System.out.println(list);
       }


       br.close();
   }catch (IOException e){
       System.out.println("Error Reading FIle");
   }
}
```

my data class

```
public class data extends States{
private String state;
private String total;
private String land;
private String water;
private String waterperc;

public data(String state, String total, String land, String water, String waterperc){



    this.state = state;
    this.total = total;
    this.land = land;
    this.water = water;
    this.waterperc = waterperc;
}

public String state(){
    return state;
}

public void getState(String state){
    this.state = state;
}

public String total(){
    return total;
}

public void getTotal(String total){
    this.total = total;
   }

public String land(){
    return land;
}

public void getLand(String land){
    this.land = land;
}
public String water(){
    return water;
}

public void getWater(String water){
    this.water = water;
}
public String waterperc(){
    return waterperc;
}

public void getWaterperc(String waterperc){
    this.waterperc = waterperc;
}
}
```

I'm pretty new at coding so please be nice haha!

When i try to convert the array from the second to the last, it won't let me convert the data from my `String` to `double`.

Am I missing something or am I just completely just not understanding?

Comment: *when i try to convert the array from the second to the last*: what does that mean? What exact and complete error do you get? Hint: how many times do you call readLine()?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JAVA - import CSV to ArrayList](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7712524/java-import-csv-to-arraylist)

Comment: I guess it should be `while((read = br.readLine()) != null)`! And what's the use of variable `line`?

Comment: Maybe you need to use type Object 
//
ArrayList<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
//
 for your list. It's more common approach

Comment: well the csv file is like this  North Carolina,140,130,13,10
Indiana,94,93,1.5,1.6
Wyoming,250,250,1.9,0.70